# Subtract successive rows in a dataframe grouped by id in pandas(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, data-science

I have the following data frame:

```
id        day           total_amount
 1       2015-07-09         1000
 1       2015-10-22          100
 1       2015-11-12          200
 1       2015-11-27         2392
 1       2015-12-16          123
 7       2015-07-09          200
 7       2015-07-09         1000
 7       2015-08-27       100018
 7       2015-11-25         1000
 8       2015-08-27         1000
 8       2015-12-07        10000
 8       2016-01-18          796
 8       2016-03-31        10000
15       2015-09-10         1500
15       2015-09-30         1000
```

I need to subtract every two successive time in day column if they have the same id until reaching the last row of that id then start subtracting times in day column this time for new id, something similar to following lines in output is expected:

```
 1       2015-08-09         1000 2015-11-22 - 2015-08-09
 1       2015-11-22          100 2015-12-12 - 2015-11-22
 1       2015-12-12          200 2015-12-16 - 2015-12-12
 1       2015-12-16         2392 2015-12-27 - 2015-12-27
 1       2015-12-27          123         NA
 7       2015-08-09          200 2015-09-09 - 2015-08-09
 7       2015-09-09         1000 2015-09-27 - 2015-09-09
 7       2015-09-27       100018 2015-12-25 - 2015-09-27
 7       2015-12-25         1000         NA
 8       2015-08-27         1000  2015-12-07 - 2015-08-27
 8       2015-12-07        10000  2016-02-18 - 2015-12-07
 8       2016-02-18          796   2016-04-31- 2016-02-18     
 8       2016-04-31        10000         NA
15       2015-10-10         1500  2015-10-30 - 2015-10-10
15       2015-10-30         1000         NA
```

Comment: @exp1orer appreciate your help

Comment: @AMM i'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['dif'] = df.groupby('id')['day'].diff(-1) * (-1)
print (df)
    id        day  total_amount      dif
0    1 2015-07-09          1000 105 days
1    1 2015-10-22           100  21 days
2    1 2015-11-12           200  15 days
3    1 2015-11-27          2392  19 days
4    1 2015-12-16           123      NaT
5    7 2015-07-09           200   0 days
6    7 2015-07-09          1000  49 days
7    7 2015-08-27        100018  90 days
8    7 2015-11-25          1000      NaT
9    8 2015-08-27          1000 102 days
10   8 2015-12-07         10000  42 days
11   8 2016-01-18           796  73 days
12   8 2016-03-31         10000      NaT
13  15 2015-09-10          1500  20 days
14  15 2015-09-30          1000      NaT
```

Another solution with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('id')['day'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1) - x)
print (df)
    id        day  total_amount     diff
0    1 2015-07-09          1000 105 days
1    1 2015-10-22           100  21 days
2    1 2015-11-12           200  15 days
3    1 2015-11-27          2392  19 days
4    1 2015-12-16           123      NaT
5    7 2015-07-09           200   0 days
6    7 2015-07-09          1000  49 days
7    7 2015-08-27        100018  90 days
8    7 2015-11-25          1000      NaT
9    8 2015-08-27          1000 102 days
10   8 2015-12-07         10000  42 days
11   8 2016-01-18           796  73 days
12   8 2016-03-31         10000      NaT
13  15 2015-09-10          1500  20 days
14  15 2015-09-30          1000      NaT
```

EDIT by comment:

If you need difference in `hours` as `int`, convert `timedelta` to `hour`:

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('id')['day'].diff(-1) * (-1) / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
print (df)
    id        day  total_amount    diff
0    1 2015-07-09          1000  2520.0
1    1 2015-10-22           100   504.0
2    1 2015-11-12           200   360.0
3    1 2015-11-27          2392   456.0
4    1 2015-12-16           123     NaN
5    7 2015-07-09           200     0.0
6    7 2015-07-09          1000  1176.0
7    7 2015-08-27        100018  2160.0
8    7 2015-11-25          1000     NaN
9    8 2015-08-27          1000  2448.0
10   8 2015-12-07         10000  1008.0
11   8 2016-01-18           796  1752.0
12   8 2016-03-31         10000     NaN
13  15 2015-09-10          1500   480.0
14  15 2015-09-30          1000     NaN
```

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('id')['day'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1) - x) / 
                                     np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
print (df)
    id        day  total_amount    diff
0    1 2015-07-09          1000  2520.0
1    1 2015-10-22           100   504.0
2    1 2015-11-12           200   360.0
3    1 2015-11-27          2392   456.0
4    1 2015-12-16           123     NaN
5    7 2015-07-09           200     0.0
6    7 2015-07-09          1000  1176.0
7    7 2015-08-27        100018  2160.0
8    7 2015-11-25          1000     NaN
9    8 2015-08-27          1000  2448.0
10   8 2015-12-07         10000  1008.0
11   8 2016-01-18           796  1752.0
12   8 2016-03-31         10000     NaN
13  15 2015-09-10          1500   480.0
14  15 2015-09-30          1000     NaN
```

Comment: The logic seems correct but i need the time difference

Comment: Absolutely the best answer, how can i change the code if i want to have the time difference in other units for example  i have these two times : 2015-10-22 08:45:30 and 2015-07-09 10:11:47 how can i find the difference in hours instead of day

Comment: What is desired `dtypes` of column `diff` - `int` or `timedelta`?

Comment: I get a ValueError when i run df['dif'] = df.groupby('id')['day'].diff(-1) * (-1)

Comment: The problem was in my data sets , day column was string, converted it to diatomite and your code works now